# When page refresh my ngnix server gives 404 not found error

Tags: angular, nginx

**Problem:**

I have built angular application and then I host it on a virtual machine using Nginx docker container for that I have created a ./Dockerfile like this.

```
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY ./dist/HRM-Front-end /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
EXPOSE 3003
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is my app-routing.module.ts file.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {HomeMainComponent} from '../module/home/feature/home-main/home-main.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeMainComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
    })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

And then nginx.conf file like this.

## on alpine, copy to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user                            root;
worker_processes                auto;

error_log                       /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

events {
    worker_connections          1024;
}

http {
    include                     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type                application/octet-stream;
    sendfile                    off;
    access_log                  off;
    keepalive_timeout           3000;
    server {
        listen                  3003;
        root                    /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index                   index.html;
        server_name             localhost;
        client_max_body_size    16m;
    }
}
```

After running the server I can access it in the browser successfully but when I try to refresh the page it gives me 404 Not found issue. I try to figure out what is the issue. But I was unable to do it can someone help me to solve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see you will have to add fallback for every route * serve index.html in htaccess
Look for nginx configuration https://angular.io/guide/deployment